# How to set default controller for link_to on rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create an image link with rails 4 partially works

```
<%= link_to("guess/index", item_id: "#{item.id}") do %>
<%= image_tag item.image, class: "img-responsive" %>
<% end %>
```

I am using this inside the guess/index view and my url id

```
http://localhost:3000/guess
```

So the first time I click the link correctly gets me to

```
http://localhost:3000/guess/index
```

The second time though it appends both the controller and action to the url

```
http://localhost:3000/guess/index
```

Can I set a default controller for the link and do something like

```
<%= link_to("index", item_id: "#{item.id}") do %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the "/" in your link.

```
<%= link_to ("/guess/index", item_id: "#{item.id}") do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Add the "/" before "guess".